# Using Serialization to save and read files in Java

Tags: java, oop, serialization, deserialization

I'm trying to use Serialization in Java to save a "Tweet" object to a file "tweet.ser" and then read the file.

This is my code for saving and reading via serialization:

```js
public class SaveRead {
  public static void save(Tweet tweet) {
    try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("tweet.ser"); ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);) {
      oos.writeObject(tweet);
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
      System.out.println("Problem saving tweet");
      ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public static Tweet loadTweet() {
    Tweet tweet = new Tweet("", "");

    try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("tweet.ser"); ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);) {
      tweet = (Tweet) ois.readObject();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
      System.out.println("Error reading file");
      ioe.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
      System.out.println("Error loading treets");
      cnfe.printStackTrace();
    }
    return tweet;
  }
}
```

This is how I create a Tweet object and try to save and read it:

```js
public static void main(String[] args) {
  // TODO code application logic here
  Tweet tweet = new Tweet("Programmer", "I can program in java.");
  SaveRead.save(tweet);
  Tweet reLoaded = SaveRead.loadTweet();
  System.out.println(reLoaded);
}
```

I can see the "tweet.ser" file created in the project folder, but the problem is that my program doesn't read the saved tweet correctly. I am expecting the reLoaded tweet to say "Programmer", "I can program in java". But all I get is this: **serialization.Tweet@232204a1**

Comment: Add a `toString()` method in the Tweet class.

Comment: Have you correctly overriden the `toString()` method in the `Tweet` class? That's the one you're invoking on the last line of your `main` method.

Comment: Note that the code you posted can't possibly be the one you're executing: it writes to tweet.txt and reads from tweet.ser. But yes, everything is fine. You're just printing a tweet, but have not defined how a tweet is supposed to be transformed to a String, thus using the default Object implementation of toString().

Comment: @Henrik and JB Nizet: You guys are right. I need to override the toString() method to print the tweet in the format I want. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Henrik for the comment and solution, I needed to add and override the toString() method in my Tweet class to get the output in the format I wanted when deserializing the saved tweet.ser file.